# What does "No suitable request handler found for (null)" mean?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm seeing "No suitable request handler found for (null)" when writing ES6 and React Native code. The React Native stack trace just drops me into Objective-C code and the error message isn't very helpful. I'm not quite sure what this error or where exactly it's coming from. Has anyone seen this before?

[image: RN error message]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the URL you are passing through to `fetch()` is not null. If you pass in a null URL you will get this error.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Network/RCTNetworking.m#L404

Comment: This is it. The URL I passed into fetch was a constant and wasn't being imported correctly, so I was passing `undefined` into fetch.

Comment: also make sure to specify the protocol `http://` or `https://` it does make a difference!