# Error:NO suitable request handler found, when fetching graphql query in react-native

Tags: react-native, graphql

hai i m trying to fetch the graphql service in react-native,but it giving an error 
No suitable request handler found for graphql url
[image]

i wrote the code like this for fetching

```
var string = "mutation M { signUp(email:\""+email+"\",password:\""+password+"\",devicetoken: \"1234567\",devicetype: \"IOS\", version: \"5.1\") {_id,email,password}}"
   fetch(REQUEST_URL,{
       method:'POST',
       headers:{
           'Accept':'application/json',
          'content-Type':'application/graphql'
       },
      body:string
  })
```

can any tell me that is there any wrong in mycode,give me suggestions that how to fetch the graphql query in react-native,Any help much appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33309063/what-does-no-suitable-request-handler-found-for-null-mean

Does your URL not have http:// prepended to it?